# CSS Help - Float Right ignoring margin

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons inside of a form and I want to position one to the left (previous) and the other to the right (next/submit). The problem is when I have the previous button hidden (which I do when on the first tab of the form) the next/submit button hovers outside of the content. How do I get the buttons positioned the way I want when the previous button is hidden?

**ASP.NET:**

```
  <div id="formContainer" style="padding:20px; margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:20px; width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:solid black 1px;background-color:#c6c6c6">
        <div id="recipeForm1">
              <!-- OMMITTED FOR Length Purposes -->
        </div>
        <div id="recipeForm2">
             <!-- OMMITTED FOR Length Purposes -->
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="recipeForm3">
            directions
        </div>
        <div id="recipeForm4">
            Nutrition
        </div>

        <div id="recipeForm5">
            review
        </div>
        <div id="buttons"style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding-top:30px;">
            <input id="btnPrevious" type="button" value="Previous" /> 
            <input id="btnNext" type="button" value="Next" style=" float:right;" />
        </div>

    </div>
```

I use jquery .show and .hide on the recipe divs and buttons as needed. When I am on recipeform1 the previous button is missing and the form looks like:

[image]

I want it to look like this (minus previous appearing):
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *clearfix* solution...

```
#buttons {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

This happens because you have floated the *next* button to the right, so when the *previous* is hidden, its parent element collapses (elements do not expand to contain floated elements by default).